# How do I specify that a Func object doesn't return null with JetBrains annotations?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I have a bit of code:

```
public void Foo([NotNull] Func<string> bar)
{
    //whatever
}
```

My problem is, the [NotNull] annotation is specifying that bar itself is not null. I'm looking instead for an annotation that says that the thing RETURNED BY BAR is not null.

I expected that this was possible but it doesn't seem to be. They support ItemNotNull for IEnumerables so I don't see why we can't have ReturnsNotNull for Func objects.

Am I just missing something obvious here? Surely something this basic is supported.

Comment: Good question, I don't think it's currently possible with annotations...

Comment: `ItemCanBeNull` might be a good candidate for extension though.

Comment: When/if the long-mooted change to C# to allow 'unnullable types' comes in, you could say `Func<string!> bar` (or whatever the syntax turns out to be). Might be quite a long wait though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now a thing in C# 8.0, with the introduction of [Nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references).

We can now do:

```
Func<string> //describes a not-null func that returns a not-null string
Func?<string> //describes a nullable func that returns a not-null string
Func<string?> //describes a not-null func that returns a nullable string
Func?<string?> //describes a nullable func that returns a nullable  string
```