# Tell resharper that a Func<string> will never return null

Tags: c#, null, resharper, code-analysis, static-analysis

```
[NotNull]
private readonly Func<string> FunctionThatWillNeverBeNullNorReturnNull;

void Test(){

    string thisStringIsNotNull = FunctionThatWillNeverBeNullNorReturnNull();
}
```

How do I tell resharper that the above function will never return null? Putting [NotNull] implies that the Function reference cannot be null, but I'm unsure how to tell resharper that what it returns won't be null either.

Comment: same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35091582/how-do-i-specify-that-a-func-object-doesnt-return-null-with-jetbrains-annotatio (no answers so can't close as dupe)

Answer (score 0):

What I do is create a delegate which can be annotated.

However, ReSharper will not show warnings for the return value. It works only for delegate parameters.

```
[CanBeNull]
public delegate string ReturnMaybeNull();

[NotNull]
public delegate string ReturnNotNull([NotNull]string someParam);

[NotNull]
private readonly ReturnMaybeNull FunctionThatMayReturnNull = () => null;

[NotNull]
private readonly ReturnNotNull FunctionThatNeverReturnsNull = someParam => null; // no warning

void Test()
{
    bool test = FunctionThatMayReturnNull().Equals(""); // no warning
    string thisStringIsNotNull = FunctionThatNeverReturnsNull(null); // parameter warning here
    if (thisStringIsNotNull == null) // no warning
    {
        test = test ^ true;
    }
}
```